# Offering "Change user" functionality when requesting authorisation of Facebook app

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

Facebook app requesting the basic authorisation (public profile).

If a user isn't logged into Facebook, it will ask them to first login. All good.

If a user is logged in, it will bypass the login step and ask for authorisation. Also good.

But in this second case, I'd like to be able to have a "Change User" or "Not you?" possibility in case the user needs to be changed.

Otherwise I'll have to somehow instruct my not-to-savvy users to click on the wrong user's name to go to that Facebook account, log out and restart my authorisation procedure again.

I considered having my own a dialog at the start showing the currently logged-in user giving the ability to change it, but I can't see the logged-in user's name unless I already have authorisation, nor can I log that user out with prior authorisation either, it seems.

Comment: Just call `FB.logout` to log the user out of Facebook …?

Comment: FB.logout requires an access token, which I won't have because the user didn't original login via my javascript, if I understand correctly.